# Add bootstrap to ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio on Mac OS

Tags: bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-mac

I want to add bootstrap 4 to my asp.net core 2.2 on my Mac OS device. I have added it by Nuget but it doesn't seem to work.

I also do not have `manage client-side library` as well as `manage Bower packages` option. VS on Mac is different from on Windows so I have some problems.

Comment: try to avoid bower - it's fallen out of favour to other bundling & minifying packages like yarn.  https://medium.com/netscape/bye-bye-bower-or-how-to-migrate-from-bower-to-npm-and-webpack-4eb2e1121a50

Comment: why dont you use cdn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Manually without Nuget.
Just Copy bootstrap all CSS and js file into your .net core project in Following Directory
**wwwroot** (you can find it in root)

And then put CSS and js links in **~/view/shared/_Layout.cshtml** Like This

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

And end of the page before

> `</body>`

tag you can put jquery and bootstrap js like this

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

that is not required to add CSS and js in

> Layout.cshtml

you can add this js and css on any page but **Layout.cshtl** is root page so that bootstrap will apply globally on your site

Answer (score 1):

Delete folder bootstrap (`wwwroot/lib/bootstrap`). Right click on the project and choose <kbd>Add</kbd> >> <kbd>Client-Side Library</kbd>. Select **twitter-bootstrap@4.5.2** with a *Target Location* set to `wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/`.

Edit `_Layout.cshtml` and change /4.3.1 and integrity:

[image: change /4.3.1 and integrity]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"/>
```

From [bootstrapcdn](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) change to:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"/>
```

and

```html
<script src=https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o"></script>
```

to:

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-LtrjvnR4Twt/qOuYxE721u19sVFLVSA4hf/rRt6PrZTmiPltdZcI7q7PXQBYTKyf"></script>
```

Comment: Now he has a suggestion, he should try.
I tried on Windows and Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache